# Published a new Chrome extension and when I am trying to download it to test, it is broken

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

So I tried to create a new Chrome extension for the Chrome web store, and everything seemed to upload and publish correctly.

However now when I try to load the page for the extension, it is broken.

Chrome gives me this error in the console:

```
POST https://chrome.google.com/webstore/ajax/detail?hl=en-US&gl=US&pv=20170811&mce=atf%2Cpii%2Crtr%2Crlb%2Cgtc%2Chcn%2Csvp%2Cwtd%2Cnrp%2Chap%2Cnma%2Cc3d%2Cncr%2Cctm%2Cac%2Chot%2Ceuf%2Cmac%2Cfcf%2Crma%2Crae%2Cshr%2Cesl%2Cigb&id=gpgcbiaclhpaiknckdfdpbjkdgfkimmo&container=CHROME&_reqid=706656&rt=j 404 ()
```

And I get the error message:

```
There was a problem loading the item. Please refresh the page and try again.
```

As far as I can tell, my manifest.json is correct:

```
{
    "name": "Chinese Personalized Colors",
    "version": "0.0.0.1",
    "short_name": "CPC",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "description": "Color code individual Chinese characters",
    "options_ui": {
        "chrome_style": true,
        "page": "options.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*", "file:///*/*", "\u003Call_urls>"],
            "css": ["mystyles.css"],
            "js": ["jquery-1.7.2.min.js", "highlight_class_version.js", "content.js"],
            "all_frames": true
        }

    ],
    "permissions": ["storage", "http://*/*"],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["dict.js", "main.js", "background.js"]
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "CPC"
    },
    "icons": {
        "128": "cpc-128px.png",
        "48": "cpc-48px.png",
        "16": "cpc-16px.png"
    },
    "author": "My Name",
    "web_accessible_resources": ["css/*", "js/*", "images/*"]
}
```

All the images and all the files above exist in the zip uploaded to Google.

I tried logging out and logging back in as this was recommended advice by some people.

What could be wrong? Could it just be that the app hasn't been published for long enough to work correctly? The stack trace isn't really telling me much and I can't find any documentation on recent uploads causing an error like this anywhere.

Comment: Did you test this locally?

Comment: Yeah, it works fine locally

Comment: If it works fine locally, there should be something wrong with your files' paths. I'm investigating this right now.

Comment: Everything is in the same (top level) directory as the manifest.json file, except for two files in a /data directory.

Comment: I installed your extension. I'm testing it and there are multiple errors.

Comment: line #45 content.js    char_return is null

Comment: line #64 dict.js Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Comment: It appears to be loading without any changes on my part so my guess is just that it took some time to get into the Web Store. And yes, there are a few bugs in it still. I'm releasing it in beta (the version number is now 0.0.0.2) because nothing else like it currently exists, and the bugs aren't total show stoppers. I've thrown in a few fixes around line #45 and I am throwing in a disclaimer that it is in beta and to expect bugs and potential performance degradation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It started working with no uploaded changes on my part. As far as I can tell, sometimes it takes time for an app to propagate to the Web Store, even when the listing appears.